# Como minificar HTML com PHP sem afetar as tags <pre> e <textarea>?

Tags: php

Ao tentar minificar um HTML com a função abaixo, tenho problemas com as tags que preservam o espaçamento apresentado no código.

A função é a seguinte:

```php
function compressHtml( $buffer ) {
    if( $this->_app->getEnvironment() == 'development' ) {
        return $buffer;
    }
    $pattern = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',         // limpando espaços em branco antes das tags
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',         // limpando espaços em branco depois das tags
        '/(\s)+/s',             // diminuindo espaços repetidos para um apenas
        '/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/',    // retirando comentários do HTML
        '#(?://)?<!\[CDATA\[(.*?)(?://)?\]\]>#s' // deixando CDATA sozinho
    );
    $replacement = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1',
        '',
        "//<![CDATA[\n".'\1'."\n//]]>"
    );
    $html = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $buffer );
    return trim( $html );
}
```

Após isso já utilizo o GZIP para comprimir e tenho conhecimento de bibliotecas que fazem esse trabalho, porem eu queria algo manual para não ter que lidar com muitas dependências de biblioteca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função que apresentada pode ser substituída pela debaixo, porem é necessário cuidados com CSS e Javascript inline.

```php
function compressHtml($buffer)
{
    // Iniciando variáveis para busca de tags
    $foundTxt = null;
    $foundPre = null;
    $foundCode = null;
    $foundScript = null;

    // Procurando tags textarea, pre, code e script
    preg_match_all('#\<textarea.*\>.*\<\/textarea\>#Uis', $buffer, $foundTxt);
    preg_match_all('#\<pre.*\>.*\<\/pre\>#Uis', $buffer, $foundPre);
    preg_match_all('#\<code.*\>.*\<\/code\>#Uis', $buffer, $foundCode);
    preg_match_all('#\<script.*\>.*\<\/script\>#Uis', $buffer, $foundScript);

    // Substitui o canteúdo da tags por uma palavra chave, assim
    // o conteúdo pode ser posto novamente intacto no lugar.
    // Exemplo: <textarea>$index</textarea> / <pre>$index</pre>
    $buffer = str_replace($foundTxt[0], array_map(function($el){ return '<textarea>'.$el.'</textarea>'; }, array_keys($foundTxt[0])), $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace($foundPre[0], array_map(function($el){ return '<pre>'.$el.'</pre>'; }, array_keys($foundPre[0])), $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace($foundCode[0], array_map(function($el){ return '<code>'.$el.'</code>'; }, array_keys($foundCode[0])), $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace($foundScript[0], array_map(function($el){ return '<script>'.$el.'</script>'; }, array_keys($foundScript[0])), $buffer);

    // Minifica o html
    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',         // Limpando espaços em branco antes das tags
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',         // Limpando espaços em branco depois das tags
        '/(\s)+/s',             // Siminuindo espaços repetidos para um apenas
        '/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/',    // Eetirando comentários do HTML
        '#(?://)?<!\[CDATA\[(.*?)(?://)?\]\]>#s' // Deixando CDATA em linhas separadas
    );

    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1',
        '',
        "//<![CDATA[\n".'\1'."\n//]]>"
    );

    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);

    // Replacing back with content
    $buffer = str_replace(array_map(function($el){ return '<textarea>'.$el.'</textarea>'; }, array_keys($foundTxt[0])), $foundTxt[0], $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace(array_map(function($el){ return '<pre>'.$el.'</pre>'; }, array_keys($foundPre[0])), $foundPre[0], $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace(array_map(function($el){ return '<code>'.$el.'</code>'; }, array_keys($foundCode[0])), $foundCode[0], $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace(array_map(function($el){ return '<script>'.$el.'</script>'; }, array_keys($foundScript[0])), $foundScript[0], $buffer);

    return $buffer;
}
```

Esta não é a melhor solução, porem é o básico do processo.